# Weekly and Monthly Decomposition of Daily Time Series

Tags: time-series, decomposition

I have a data set including daily prices and demand of a commodity. I am sure that, price and demand weekly and monthly changing. So it has a seasonality effect. How can I decompose it by using daily data ?

My data looks like this ;

[image]

The row number is 335 . So the last date is 2016-11-30.

I will try to catch a relationship between price and demand. But, not to face with a spurious regression, I have to decompose it first. Using weekly and monthly dummies is an option, but I want to use stl() or decompose() functions, or another one maybe.

I start with : ts(data$Price, start=c(2016,1,1),frequency=365)

But that one also does not work! I couldn't achieve to transform it to *timeseries data*!

Comment: Please explain the statistical question here. If you are simply seeking R advice, the post is, it seems, off-topic.

Comment: Well, I am pretty new in this site. Should I ask R-based questions in somewhere else ?

Comment: You should try `as.ts()`. The link below may help: https://anomaly.io/seasonal-trend-decomposition-in-r/

Comment: The problem is coming from the usage of daily data sets in R. The link you shared is related with montly or yearly data. Daily data is a problematic issue..

Comment: Daily data is not a problem for methods / software that I use . Are you still having a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use a msts object (defined in the forecast package) which handles multiple seasonality time series. Then you can specify all the frequencies that might be relevant. It is also flexible enough to handle non-integer frequencies.
Data    frequencies
         minute     hour    day     week    year
Daily                                7    365.25

Y <- msts(x, seasonal.periods=c(7,365,25)